# How do you log out of Firebase? (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to log out users from my app. In the Firebase API, it says to use `[ref unauth];`

What exactly is the ref that I'm supposed to unauthorize? Is it a Firebase reference or the user's uid? I've used a Firebase reference, and it doesn't seem to do anything. How do I use this command? What exactly is it supposed to do? I haven't come across a good example.

Comment: Looking at the docs, it's the same `ref` you use to log your users in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase client manages the connection to its servers behind the scenes and authenticates on that connection instead of per `Firebase` object. This means that whenever you call for example `ref authUser:@"jenny@example.com" password:@"correcthorsebatterystaple"` on any  `Firebase` reference, the user is authenticated on all references.

Similarly: when you call `unauth` on any `Firebase` reference, the user will be signed out of all references in your app.

Comment: OK, what if i'm using Facebook log in via Firebase UI?

Comment: That makes no different to the Firebase Authentication part. If you're having problems with it, post the code that is giving problems.

Comment: `[[FIRAuth auth] signOut:nil];`

Answer (score 4):

```
NSError *signOutError;
BOOL status = [[FIRAuth auth] signOut:&signOutError];
if (!status) {
    NSLog(@"Error signing out: %@", signOutError);
    return;
}else{
    NSLog(@"Successfully Signout");
}
```

Implement this code you must enjoy that it works for sign out.